# How to draw a dynamic table in c

Tags: c, formatting, printf

I want to draw a dynamic table with c language that get values from an array of struct.
I have tried this way to draw the table:

```
            printf("ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»\n");
            printf("º                               EMPRUNTEURS                               º\n");
            printf("º                              _____________                              º\n");
            printf("º                                                                         º\n");
            printf("º    ÚÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÂÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÂÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ¿   º\n");
            printf("º    ³   Matricule     ³         Nom & Prenom       ³       Classe    ³   º\n");
            printf("º    ÃÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÅÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÅÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ´   º\n");
            printf("º    ³                 ³                            ³                 ³   º\n");
            printf("º    ÃÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÅÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÅÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ´   º\n");
            printf("º    ³                 ³                            ³                 ³   º\n");
            printf("º    ÃÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÅÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÅÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄ´   º\n");
            printf("º    ³                 ³                            ³                 ³   º\n");
            printf("º    ÀÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÁÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÁÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÄÙ   º\n");
            printf("ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼\n");
```

But the problem is when I want to fill this table from the array how can I do it without losing the design?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make use of [`printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)'s formatting specifications, and define the optional width and precision of each field that you print:

```
%[flags][width][.precision][length]specifier
```

So you'd not use `"%d"` or `"%s"`  which produce a variable length output, but `"%11d"` to produce 11 digits, or `"%-25.25s"` to use minimum and maximum 25 chars (`-` means left justification).  Note that you are not bound to fixed size : you could use `*` to provide width or precision as additional argument.

Here an example:

```
printf("+=================+============================+=================+\n");
printf("|   Matricule     |         Nom & Prenom       |       Classe    |\n");
printf("+=================+============================+=================+\n");
for (int i=0; i<MX; i++) {
     printf("| %11d     | %-25.25s  | %-*.*s  |\n", mat[i],name[i],14,14,classe[i]);
}        
printf("+=================+============================+=================+\n");
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/Rix3PY)